# Linear scan for comparing two arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am currently attempting to write an algorithm that can scan two arrays for equality in O(N) time, using Java. The idea is that the arrays should be exactly equal, regardless of order, for the method to return true. What was recommended to me was to use linear scan, but use one loop to scan and compare two arrays. This is what I have:

```
   public boolean equals(ArraySet<T> s) {
  T[] sArray = s.getArray();
  boolean isEqual = true;
  if (!(s.size() == size())) {
     return false;
  }
  int i = 0;
  int p = 0;
  while ((i < elements.length) && (p < sArray.length)) {
     if (elements[i].compareTo(sArray[p]) != 0) {
        isEqual = false;
        p++;
        continue;
     }
     i++;
     p = 0;
     isEqual = true;
  }
  return isEqual;
```

I'm confident that this algorithm will return the equality correctly, but I'm not so sure that it will do so in O(N) time complexity. Is there anything I could tweak to ensure that this method functions with the proper efficiency? ArraySet is a Set implementation that contains an array field, returned by getArray(). This array and the local array can be assumed to already be in ascending natural order, however the parameter array and the local array can obviously not be assumed to have the same elements.

Comment: First, I suggest writing some tests to check that your algorithm is correct.

Comment: What is `elements`?

Comment: See if `1,2,2` and `2,1,1` would compare as equal.

Comment: It doesn't work. I honestly have no idea what's wrong with it at this point.

Comment: Your solution only work if both array are sorted. You can also achieve O(n) by counting the number of element then check both has same number of elements or not. Take a `count[]` initialized to `zero`. Then loop through each index  and increment and decrement count `count[element[i]] ++; count[sArray[i]]--`. And finally check all of count array has all zero element or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are doing in your while loop isn't correct. 
Scenario 1: Even if we assume both array's are sorted, in your while loop you are incrementing only p and not i. That is if you have two arrays: element={1,2,3} sArray={1,2,3}; you are just comparing element[0] with rest of sArray.

Scenario 2:Let's say both arrays equal in length but are not in sorted order.
element={1,2,3} sArray={2,1,3}; Even here your code again just compares element[0] with rest of the sArray.

A better approach is to use a HashSet and compare your element array to hashset.
Here is a simple example to compare arrays:[**we are assuming there are not duplicates in the both arrays, else this solution wont work]**

```
Set<Integer> uniqueList = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int[] elements={1,2,3};
        int[] sArray = {3,2,1};
        boolean isArrayElementsEqual = false;

        for(int i=0;i<sArray.length;i++){
            uniqueList.add(sArray[i]);// add one of the arrays complete elements into a set
        }

        for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            if(uniqueList.contains(elements[i])){//compare another array elements with the set, if its exists them remove it from set..such that by the end of this if both arrays have equal contents, set should be empty
                uniqueList.remove(elements[i]);

            }
        }

        if(uniqueList.isEmpty()){//if this list is empty it means both arrays have same contents
            isArrayElementsEqual = true;
            return isArrayElementsEqual;
        }

        return isArrayElementsEqual;
```

P.S: You could modify it based on your requirement

Comment: Your solution works but wrong one. Complexity of your solution if O(n^2). Because `uniqueList.contains(elements[i])` has `O(n)` complexity and outer loop `for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++)` has also `O(n)` complexity, so altogether complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @rahul kindly look at the code properly.. there are not two loops in here.. its two separate loops.. the complexity is O(n+n) which is (2n).. we dont consider constants.. so complexity is still O(n)..
n^2, n^3.. n^n happens only if we have nested loops.. do you find nested loops in my  code?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{
            if(uniqueList.contains(elements[i]))
             {
                uniqueList.remove(elements[i]);

            }
        }`

Only this portion itself has O(n^2) complexity.  Because uniqueList.contains(elements[i]) has O(n) complexity. Please read my previous comment carefully.

Comment: Rahul, may be there is a confusion you need to clear.. API documentation guide and many many questions asked in SO and other sites have proved that contains happens in O(1) constant time. 
**The expected time is O(1), since the average number of keys in each bucket of the HashSet is bound by a small constant. At the worst case (if all the keys are mapped to the same bucket), the search would take linear time, but unless you have a terrible hashCode method, the worst case is not expected to ever happen**